# Show Advanced custom field in wpallexport

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, export, advanced-custom-fields

I wanted to export a Advanced custom field and therefore I used the Function Editor in wpallexport, but nothing is showing up.
I created a ACF field for the product in woocommerce (`wirtschaftlicher_eigentumer`), I tried to get it over the `product_id` but nothing appears.

```php
function wirtschaftlicher_eigen ($product_id) {
    if ( ! empty($product_id) ) {
        return get_field('wirtschaftlicher_eigentumer', 'product_' . $product_id);
    }
}
```

Want to get the field but instead it's empty.

Comment: Have you checked if the custom field has saved data in the database?

Comment: yes, i've checked this and i only get the pruduct_id not the ACF field

Comment: Did it:
function wirtschaftlicher_eigen( $product_id ) {
 if ( ! empty( $product_id ) ) {
  return get_field( 'wirtschaftlicher_eigentumer', $product_id );
 }
}

Comment: Is it working @Gatti?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
return get_field('wirtschaftlicher_eigentumer', 'product_' . $product_id);
```

To

```
return get_field('wirtschaftlicher_eigentumer', $product_id);
```

The `$product_id` will return the current post id.